# Updating data from Google sheet tab with queried data back to original tab

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am working on a Google app script to practice to understand working with arrays in Google Sheets before starting on a larger project.

I have two tabs in the sheet. The first with a range of data like a account register, the second with a filtered array of transactions form the first sheet that need paid. My goal with this script would be to read which transactions have "Paid" marked in a column and go back to the original sheet and mark them off as paid. The first column of both arrays is a unique id.

I think that my problem is how I am declaring the variables from my for loops.

Any direction on what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.

```
function updatePaid() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var paid = ss.getSheets()[2];// sheet containing filtered data
  var lPaid = paid.getLastRow();
  var pData = paid.getRange(1,6,lPaid,6);// range containg values of filtered data
  var data = ss.getSheets()[1];// sheet containing entire register of data
  var lData = data.getLastRow();
  var dData = data.getRange(1,1,lData,10);//range containg original data
  var x=0;
  var id=0;
  // for loop to identify filtered data marked "Paid"
  for(i=0;i<pData.length;++i){
    if(pData[i][5]='Paid'){
      id = pData[i][1];
      // for loop to find matching transaction on original data
      for(a=0;a<dData.length;++a){
        if(dData[a][0]=id){
          x = i;
        }
      // two different attemps to mark transaction in orignial data as "Paid"
      data.getRange(x,10).setValue('Paid');
      ss.getSheets()[1].getRange(x,10).setValue('Paid');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should acquire the values by using `.getValues()` after selecting the data range. When setting a value, keep in mind that when you are iterating over the array, pData[0] equals the data in row 1. So when you select a range to mark it as paid, you should update row `i + 1`.